# Wordpress REST API Authentication without a login page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, rest

I want to post to my wordpress blog with javascript using the REST api, I understand two step process to get authenticated
1. User sent to authorization page, user press authorize button get a code,
2. Use the code to get an access token .

I need to skip step 1. 
How can i post to my blog without user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [JSON API](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) module? Here is the [full documentation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#2.2.-Pages-controller-methods).